# How to equally and randomly assign records to user ID's in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Looking for some basic SQL help (SQL Server 2005). I have two tables that look like the following and I need to assign each record with a unique user ID:

**Record** table:

```
Record_ID    UserID
101          0
102          0
103          0
104          0
105          0
106          0
107          0
```

**User** table:

```
UserID
1
2
3
```

Update results:

```
Record_ID    UserID
101          1
102          2
103          3
104          1
105          2
106          3
107          1
```

Answer (score 1):

You trying to have mutually exclusive requirements ... 'randomly' and 'equally'.  You can't do both.

Comment: What about doing a temp table with the record ID and tagging each record row ID 1-3, then assigning the userID's an ID 1-3 and doing a match that way? Just not sure how to the over(order) function to get the records tagged with 1,2,3,4